# The Android studio's emulator only performs screen reflection when sizing

Tags: android-virtual-device

The code seems to reflect well, but it is not reflected on the screen.
It is then reflected immediately when adjusting the size of the device screen.
I can't find out what the problem is.

I want it to be reflected on the screen as soon as I run the code.
I am currently using flutter.
Even if I try various methods such as undock, floating, coldboot, use of different types of devices, etc., the screen will not be reflected immediately unless it is resized.